# Webpack 5: How to inject CSS into head tag directly

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-5

I want to place CSS in the head tag of my HTML template directly instead of loading CSS into JS. But I can't find any reliable examples how to do this.

```js
/* webpack.config.js */

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/script.js'),
  },
  output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
     filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
     clean: true,
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'My optimized file',
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/temp.html'),
      templateParameters: {
        'style': '[name].[contenthash].css' // doesn't bind with CopyPlugin
      },
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/style.css'), to: '[name].[contenthash].css' },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```

And my HTML template `src/temp.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= style %>">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello there!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Now as the result in my compiled HTML file `dist/index.html` I get this:

```html
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="[name].[contenthash].css">
</head>
```

After `webpack build` href attribute has just a wapback parameter `[name].[contenthash].css` instead of compiled CSS filename `style.347572c74109b5f9ef4e.css`.

And my folder structure:

```
dist
 ├─ index.html
 ├─ main.3d522b68c880128437a8.js
 └─ style.347572c74109b5f9ef4e.css
src
 ├─ script.js
 ├─ style.css
 └─ temp.html
webpack.config.js
package.json
```

Comment: Have you tried example provided in webpack documentation? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/ Works for me, just note that you have to use MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader in your loaders for css files

Comment: Yes, I've just tried [custom-template example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/custom-template) from `html-webpack-plugin` . But to make it work you must add extra line in your JS file: `require('./style.css');`. Why there is no solution using only `webpack.config.js` file since CSS shouldn't be hardwired with JS?

Answer (score 0):

For now I found temporary solution to this problem. I've just tried [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) and looked at [example](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/custom-template) from `html-webpack-plugin`.

```js
/* webpack.config.js */

...
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'] },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'template.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'style.css' })
  ]
```

But to make it work you must require CSS in JS file:

```js
/* script.js */

require('./style.css');
...
```

But I'm still looking for how to do it without hardcoding CSS in JS using only `webpack.config.js` file since `style.css` has nothing to do with `script.js` in my case.

Comment: I think that problem might be that you're using style loader which injects your CSS into DOM and it requires to import CSS file in JavaScript... So I think you should get rid of style loader and include MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader in your .css loaders. It should be included along with css-loader, so order should be: {test: /\.css$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, css-loader]}.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, I've already added `{ test: /\.css$/, use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'] }` to rules. I think if I find the way how to bind `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `CopyPlugin` then I will be able to add CSS in my `webpack.config.js` regardless of JS.

Comment: Also you need to require or import your CSS file because webpack needs entrypoint to your CSS - as alternative I think it should work if you'd specify separate entry in webpack configuration for your css file